# My code keeps crashing xampp

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I'm trying to create a function that will run automatically if chat_active = 1, but it just crashes xampp and makes my cpu really high and website won't respond.. here is my javascript and php file code that crashes xammp

```js
function chat_refresh(){
  document.forms["chatname"]["namechat"].value = id;
  var username = document.forms["chatname"]["namechat"].value;
  $.post( ('php/friend/chat.php'), $('#chatname :input').serializeArray(),
   function(data){
    $('#chats').html(data);
    var element = document.getElementById('chat-panel');
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("chat").focus();
    active()
    });
};
function active(){
 if(chat_active == 1){
  var time = 1000; // ms
  var endtime = 10000;  // ms
  var counter = 0;
  var start = setInterval(function(){
    chat_refresh()
    if(counter === endtime){
       clearInterval(start);
    }
    counter += time;
}, time);
 }
}
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) == ""){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">','index();','</script>';
}

require '../../php/dbConnect.php';
if (isset($_POST['namechat'])) {
$username = $_POST['namechat'];
}
$user = $_SESSION['users'];

$query = ("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `username_receive` = '$user' && `username_send` = '$username' || `username_receive` = '$username' && `username_send` = '$user'");
$response = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($response )) {
  if($row['username_send'] == $username)
  echo '
  <div>
    <img id="profile-image" src="img/'. $row['image'] .'" class="small-circle " style="display: inline-block; margin: 2% 0 0 0">
    <label id="chat-bubble" class="w3-input w3-text-white overlay border-remove round-edge " style="width: 70%; word-wrap: break-word;display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 2% 0">'. $row['chat'] .'</label>
  </div>
';
else
  echo'
    <div>
      <label id="chat-bubble" class="w3-input w3-text-white overlay border-remove round-edge " style="width: 70%; word-wrap: break-word;display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 2% 0">'. $row['chat'] .'</label>
      <img id="profile-image" src="img/'. $row['image'] .'" class="small-circle " style="display: inline-block; margin: 2% 0 0 0">
    </div>
    ';


}
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. This is hard to make sense of with the current indentation.

Comment: And please include all relevant code. What is `chat_refresh` doing?

Comment: This function doesn't involve PHP (thus apache) at all. If apache is crashing because of this, it's most likely the PHP executed by this code is the root cause. The JS probably only made it worse, executing the bad PHP several times.

Comment: this code wouldn't crash a TRS-80 - unless `chat_refresh` is doing something crazy bad, hitting the server real hard - even then, I can't see it crashing a properly configured XAMPP, unless the server side code is also crazy bad

Comment: Yeah, unless you're doing something very odd like interpreting the JS with PHP, there's not much chance of this being the cause of your issue.

Comment: im not sure what im doing wrong but when i run this code it crashes so hard

Comment: Please add chat.php code too

Comment: @PranavMS is this good ?

Comment: fixed it, removed active() on chat_refresh()

Comment: You should also look into PDO or mysqli to prevent Sql Injection attacks. Googling for "Bobby Tables" should help explain the problem succinctly. ;) Here's the classic cartoon: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @enhzflep i tried to get PDO before, but it just wouldnt work at all

Comment: @ゆきくいに - There are many, many tutorials available demonstrating correct usage of PDO. I use it exclusively and can tell you, that the convenience of being able to swap between mysql, sqlite, sql server, oracle databases simply by changing the connection string makes it worthwhile. The added protection of prepared-statements makes anything else (mysql, mysqli etc, etc) seem positively antiquated and dangerous in comparison. ;)